# oracle update two based on 2 condition from another table

Tags: database, oracle, join

I have 2 table. `TableA` and `TableB` 
I want to update `TableA` based on 2 condition, 1 condition is from `TableA` and second condition is from `TableB`.

```
UPDATE TableA SET
    TYPE = (CASE when TYPE = (SELECT DISTINCT(A.TYPE) FROM TableA A JOIN TableB B ON B.SOID = A.NAME where B.level = 9 and A.TYPE = 66) then 12
                      when TYPE = (SELECT DISTINCT(A.TYPE) FROM TableA A JOIN TableB B ON B.SOID = A.NAME where B.level = 4 and A.TYPE = 66) then 11
             else NULL 
END);
```

for some reason it is updating not correctly. I only have 3 records that meet this condition but it is updating every row it looks like.

This can done in SQL using 
The syntax for the SQL UPDATE statement when updating multiple tables (not permitted in Oracle) is:

```
UPDATE table1, table2, ... 
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
WHERE table1.column = table2.column
AND conditions;
```

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is a select function.

Comment: No it's **NOT** a function. It's an _operator_ that is applied to _all_ columns of a select list. The parentheses around the column are totally useless

Comment: ok but even that wouldn't fix my issue, I need to do a join in an update statement, I am doing inside a case statement which is messing things up. your are pointing up mistakes that doesn't fix my query.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some sample data (formatted text) and the result based on that data. It is completely unclear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please see updated example, I am trying to archieve this in Oracle not in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Lots and Lots of Google.

I found the solution. Hope it helps others.

```
    UPDATE (SELECT A.TYPE,B.LEVEL FROM TABLEA A 
            JOIN TABLEB B ON B.SOID = A.NAME where B.level IN (9,4) and A.TYPE = 66) 
    SET TYPE = (CASE (WHEN LEVEL = 9 THEN 12 
                  WHEN LEVEL = 4 THEN 11 
                  ELSE NULL 
                END);
```